# Numeric overflow Exception in java JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

This query returns a numeric overflow exception. Values from 1 to 14 are retrieved easily but bigger values (from 15 on) cannot be.

I am using ORACLE XE. How do I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
pst=con.prepareStatement("Select * from student where sut_id like 'Kul7Dub514'");
rs=pst.executeQuery();
while(rs.next)
{
    smob.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(15)));
    fmob.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(16)));
    mmob.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(17)));
    col.setText(rs.getString(18));
    address.setText(rs.getString(19));
}
```

Student's table:

```
create table student ( stu_id varchar(10) primary key, stu_image Blob,
 stu_first_name varchar(20) not null,
 stu_middle_name varchar(20) not null,
 stu_last_name varchar(20) not null,
 fat_first_name varchar(20) not null,
 fat_middle_name varchar(20),
 fat_last_name varchar(20) not null,
 mot_first_name varchar(20),
 mot_middle_name varchar(20),
 mot_last_name varchar(20),
 dob Date,
 gender varchar(6),
 ac_yr varchar(10),
 mobno number(11),
 fatmob number(11),
 motmob number(11),
 edu_center varchar(50),
 address varchar(150) )
```

Comment: what is the meta-data for the student table.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the data in your DB is `Number(11)`, this will not fit into an Integer.

Try a Long and `rs.getLong(15)`;

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you do not perform any mathematical operations with that "numbers". Since you do not treat them as numbers, but as identifiers. You should use Java type `BigDecimal`. This is a type which is most similar to Oracle datatype `NUMBER`. Or you can also use datatype provided by jdbc drivers `oracle.sql.NUMBER`.